# Regex to match all words outside tags and with accents on PHP

Tags: php, regex, diacritics, words

I want to mark all words inside a text, except the ones that are inside a tag.
Based on the idea from [here](http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/matching-a-word-characters-outside-of-html-tags/), I was able to accomplish the following:

```
preg_replace("/(\b(\p{L}+)\b)(?!([^<]+)?>)/", "<mark>$1</mark>", $input);
```

Which works fine EXCEPT for some weird behaviors when using with accent. Examples:

```
lorem ipsúm dolor <a href="#" title="sit">sit</a> amet consectetur
[OK] => <mark>lorem</mark> <mark>ipsúm</mark> <mark>dolor</mark> <a href="#" title="sit"><mark>sit</mark></a> <mark>amet</mark> <mark>consectetur</mark>

ação ipísum
[NOT OK] => <mark>a</mark>çã<mark>o</mark> <mark>ip</mark>í<mark>sum</mark>
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: it works here http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/16

Comment: @AvinashRaj, not here though: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6Sf (you must insert the replacement string; that regex101 is way better). Maybe a PHP version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's all so simple...

A couple things here:

1. You want to use the UTF-8 modifier `u`.
2. Not relevant for your sample text, but you're leaving out graphemes made of letters with combining diacritics like "è". Here encoded as "e" followed by a [combining grave accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0300/index.htm). To match those you need to add some optional `\p{M}`.

So the regex grows:

```
$input = 'lorem <a href="#">foo</a> ação';

echo preg_replace(
    '/\b((?:\p{L}\p{M}*)+)\b(?!([^<]+)?>)/u',
    "<mark>$1</mark>",
    $input
);
```

Outputs:

```
<mark>lorem</mark> <a href="#"><mark>foo</mark></a> <mark>ação</mark>
```

---

#### ...except

So far so good, right? Let's add that "è" and see.

```
$input = 'lorem <a href="#">foo</a> ação evè';
```

Nets the output:

```
<mark>lorem</mark> <a href="#"><mark>foo</mark></a> <mark>ação</mark> <mark>eve</mark>̀
```

That ain't right. Turns out the word boundary shorthand `\b` still acts a bit silly, even in utf-8 mode. So you have to replace it with some negative lookarounds.

While we're at it let's also use `\pL` in place of `\p{L}` as the curly braces are optional for single-letter Unicode categories.

---

#### Put all together:

```
$input = 'lorem <a href="#">foo</a> ação evè';

echo preg_replace(
    '/(?<![\pL\pM])((?:\pL\pM*)+)(?![\pL\pM])(?!([^<]+)?>)/u',
    "<mark>$1</mark>",
    $input
);
```

Outputs:

```
<mark>lorem</mark> <a href="#"><mark>foo</mark></a> <mark>ação</mark> <mark>evè</mark>
```

---

Demo at https://eval.in/194139.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `u` modifier:

```
$arr = Array('orem ipsúm dolor <a href="#" title="sit">sit</a> amet consectetur','ação ipísum');
foreach($arr as $input) {
    echo preg_replace("/(\b(\p{L}+)\b)(?!([^<]+)?>)/u", "<mark>$1</mark>", $input),"\n";
    //                                       here __^
}
```

**Output:**

```
<mark>orem</mark> <mark>ipsúm</mark> <mark>dolor</mark> <a href="#" title="sit"><mark>sit</mark></a> <mark>amet</mark> <mark>consectetur</mark>
<mark>ação</mark> <mark>ipísum</mark>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but as @derp explained, it would miss some characters